# Is it possible to store custom UITableViewCell into Array?

Tags: swift, uitableview, cell, subclass

I have a lot of custom cells, and wanted to streamline the `cellForRowAt` by using the struct and storing information about the cell in an array.

```
struct HowToCells {
    let helpCell: UITableViewCell
    let identifier: String
    let icon: UIImage
    let cellName: String
}

var cellArray = [HowToCells]()

cellArray.append(HowToCells.init(helpCell: ScreenRecordingTableViewCell(), identifier: "ScreenRecordingTableViewCell", icon: HowToImage.screenRecording.image(), cellName: "Enable screen recording"))

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let c = cellArray[indexPath.row]
     let cellToUse = c.helpCell

     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: c.identifier, for: indexPath) as! cellToUse

}
```

I get the following error: Use of undeclared type 'cellToUse'

`ScreenRecordingTableViewCell` is a custom UITableViewCell

Comment: This is exactly the reason why reusabele cells are introduced: to keep not-visible cells not in memory...

Comment: _"wanted to streamline the cellForRowAt by using the struct and storing information about the cell in an array."_ Then store the information in the array and not the cell itself, which btw you have to do anyway for the table to work!

Comment: @RakeshaShastri - `ScreenRecordingTableViewCell` is the actual cell in this case, which is being stored in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error on this line:
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: c.identifier, for: indexPath) as! cellToUse

because a UITableViewCell Subclass type should be used after the as!, not a variable name.  x as! y is asking to force a type cast of object X to Type Y.

That being said, you will run into issues storing cells in arrays and using tableView.dequeueReusableCell, which takes an existing cell, dequeues it and then re-uses it.  This will corrupt your data.  You need to put all the data for the cells into the array, then retrieve that index from the array in cellForRow.

Comment: Is there any recommendation from Apple that we should not store UITableViewCells?

Comment: @ReDetection. yes, cells are dequeable, meaning iOS manages their life cycle and apps should refrain to using uitableview datasource and delegate methods for interacting with them.   focus on management of the data that the view layer (cells) display and not the cells themselves

Comment: I mean do you have a link to developer.apple.com where this is explicitly stated that one should avoid of messing with cells? I believe if I don't use `dequeueReusableCell` method but create my cells in advance (very limited amount, not changing after creation), I can safely store them in array.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store table view cells in array, because UITableView creates and stores them by itself. Just use `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)` method in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` to get needed cell. After that you can configure this cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CellClass
// Configure cell
return cell
}
```