# Simplifying cellForRowAt in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am writing a personal iOS app to keep track of some things. my app is working well but i am turning my attention to tidying up the code and cleaning things up. in my tableview, one of the cells is uicollectionview that depending on which collectionviewcell I select, a custom tableviewcell is loaded in the same table. At this time I have about a dozen items in my collectionview that i can select from and in turn one of about a dozen different tableviewcells to load. each cell collects different bits of info.

everything is working as i expect it but i don't like the fact that throughout this tableviewcontroller, i have many repetitive sections based on all the tableviewcells i have to handle

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // register the various tablecells
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "eventO2TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "eventO2TableViewCell")
...
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "eventTmpTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "eventTmpTableViewCell")
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "eventDXTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "eventDXTableViewCell")
```

similarly cellForRowAt is very big (i.e a switch statement, a dozen cases , each with a corresponding

```
switch selectedIndexPath.row { // the index of the uicollectionviewcell
case 1:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventTmpTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! eventTmpTableViewCell
    return cell
...
case 11:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventO2TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! eventO2TableViewCell
    return cell
default:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventDXTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! eventDXTableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

and in

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
```

another switch statement with a dozen case evaluation to figure out which cell was used and pull out the information i need to save.

was contemplating the idea that was raised in this similar question [Is it possible to store custom UITableViewCell into Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52666645/is-it-possible-to-store-custom-uitableviewcell-into-array) but curious if there are other suggestions ? still consider myself a beginner in this space. thanks

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://medium.com/chili-labs/configuring-multiple-cells-with-generics-in-swift-dcd5e209ba16

Comment: thank you very much for this, i will review the Medium article and see how best to adapt this to my setup...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created extensions for `register` and `deque` in `UITableView` and `identifier` in `UITableViewCell`, here is some sample code:

UITableViewExtension.swift

```
public extension UITableView {

    func register<CellClass: UITableViewCell>(_ cellClass: CellClass.Type) {
        register(cellClass, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellClass.identifier)
    }

    func dequeue<CellClass: UITableViewCell>(
        _ cellClass: CellClass.Type,
        for indexPath: IndexPath,
        setup: ((CellClass) -> Void)? = nil) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellClass.identifier, for: indexPath)
        if let cell = cell as? CellClass {
            setup?(cell)
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

UITableViewCell.swift

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    static var identifier: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }
}
```

Then in ViewController.swift

```
class Cell1: UITableViewCell {
    // ...
}
class Cell2: UITableViewCell {
    // ...
}

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let cells = [Cell1.self, Cell2.self]
        tableView.register(cells)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return tableView.dequeue(Cell1.self, for: indexPath) { cell in
            // customise cell
        }
    }
}
```

Note: As you have asked I'm storing `UITableViewCell`s into cells array and get my job done. Even though there are minor changes in our implementations, I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a protocol `DequeueInitializable` and write its extension like this

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol DequeueInitializable {
    static var reuseableIdentifier: String { get }
}

extension DequeueInitializable where Self: UITableViewCell {

    static var reuseableIdentifier: String {
        return String(describing: Self.self)
    }

    static func dequeue(tableView: UITableView) -> Self {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.reuseableIdentifier) else {
            return UITableViewCell() as! Self
        }
        return cell as! Self
    }
    static func register(tableView: UITableView)  {
        let cell = UINib(nibName: self.reuseableIdentifier, bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(cell, forCellReuseIdentifier: self.reuseableIdentifier)
    }
}
```

Then in you cell class you confirm to that protocol

```
class Cell1: UITableViewCell, DequeueInitializable { }
class Cell2: UITableViewCell, DequeueInitializable { }
```

Now you can register and dequeue cell easily

```
return Cell1.dequeue(tableView: tableView)
```

to register

```
Cell1.register(tableView: tableView)
```